# Difference between "need" and "would need"

Tags: difference, verbs, auxiliary

What is the difference between "need" and "would need". For instance, on below example:

> Reason I ask is no automation scripts have been developed for deploying a AWS Tape Gateway at this stage as this is the first use case. And if this goes to production environment we **would need** some time to develop and test the automated scripts to deploy AWS Tape Gateway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "would" mean in "Don't be so nervous — anyone would think I was about to leap on you."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342728/what-does-would-mean-in-dont-be-so-nervous-anyone-would-think-i-was-about)

Answer (score 1):

A "would need" is being used as "would" acts like a auxiliary verb, where it depicts the present future tense (context is present tense). To put it simply:

> **If** goes to production environment -> then -> **need** some time

So the "if" depicts *only if* it happens, then they need more time, so we use a present future tense -> "would need".