# What does "would" mean in "Don't be so nervous — anyone would think I was about to leap on you."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, would

a sentence from extra examples of item #2 on [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/leap_1):
**(1)** *Don't be so nervous — anyone **would** think I **was** about to leap on you*.

I don't understand the choice of the verbs "would" and "was".

What does "would" mean here?
Could you show me please in a dictionary that meaning of "would" the example of which could be (1)?

Why, for using with "would", is the verb "be" selected namely in the past simple form (I mean, "was")?

---

How will the sentence meaning change if we replace "was" with "am"?:
**(2)** *Don't be so nervous — anyone **would** think I **am** about to leap on you*.
Is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?
If it is, then what is the difference between (1) and (2)?

---

I understand only sentences without "would", for example:
**(3)** *Don't be so nervous — anyone **may** think I **am** about to leap on you*.
**(4)** *Don't be so nervous — anyone **might** think I **was** about to leap on you*.
**(5)** *Don't be so nervous — anyone **might** think I **am** about to leap on you*.

(3), (4) and (5) are understandable to me because they don't have "would".
But as soon as "would" arises, I'm immediately getting confused.

Comment: It describes a hypothetical situation; if someone (who didn't know us) were to come along, they would think that I was about to leap on you.

Answer (score 1):

The would is used for a conditional. The "if" part of the condition is not expressed and must be understood from the wider context.

I understand this to be "... *If anybody saw you now, acting nervous,* [they] would think I was about to leap on you"

The past simple form is chosen as the second conditional.